# col-md-4 and col-md-8 won't float after adding a form?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

really new to Bootstrap, so bear with me please. I am just trying it out and can't seem to get these to stay floating?

I have a `col-md-4` and a `col-md-8` that float, but once this form is included in the `col-md-4`, the `col-md-8` will stop floating and just be cleared?

```
    <form class="form-center" role="form">
       <div class="form-group">
          <div class="input-group"> 
              <span class="input-group-addon">
                  <i class="fa fa-user fa-fw"></i>
              </span>                            
              <input type="text" id="username" name="username" class="form-control" placeholder="Username" />
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="password" class="sr-only">Password</label>
            <div class="input-group"> 
                <span class="input-group-addon">
                    <i class="fa fa-key fa-fw"></i>
                </span>
                <input type="password" id="password" name="password" class="form-control" placeholder="password" />
            </div>  
          <div class="checkbox">
  <label><input type="checkbox" value="">Remember Me</label>
</div>
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Create account</button>
</form>
```

Also here is a [codepen](http://codepen.io/TyStelmach/full/gpGMYW/) of the issue at hand. Appreciate all the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to close the div to `col-md-4` properly, right now `col-md-8` is inside `col-md-4` hence why it will not float beside it

What you have:

```
<div class="col-md-4">
    <form />
    <div class="col-md-8"></div>
</div>
```

What you should change it to

```
<div class="col-md-4">
    <form />
</div>
<div class="col-md-8"></div>
```

Comment: Figures it's something simple and not a bootstrap issue haha. I was looking through tons of docs on col naming conventions, thinking I named it wrong. Completely overlooked this, thanks!

Comment: There are extra closing div tags on `.col-md-4`, also. I suggest an HTML formatter/validator or a better code editor. http://brackets.io